# How to create a function that would repeat the concatenation of the one string variable per letter or number in the other column?

Tags: r

I am trying to come up with a function that would standardize the concatenation of names (Proper names of rooms) to a series of letters or numbers (subconfiguration of said rooms). The goal is to create a key which would help "dedup" the data since for example "Ballroom 2-4" and "Ballroom 4-6" would double count Ballroom 4 and so on.

In the dataframe provided below, the final output should look like the second column (accross all three dataframes below called "dedupedConfig").

One way to tackle this would be by utilizing the "splitstackshape" package whereby each value in the first column ("config" - see below) would be separated out before repasting them together with commas as seperators. This is not the most elegant solution but one that could viable. However, I fail to find a consistent pattern (or set of patterns) though which the data can be cleansed (see below). If this becomes a feasible solution, then one would simply use unite() (from tidyr) or paste() (from base) to concatenate values from multiple columns with "," acting as seperator.

Below is an exhaustive (and exhausting) set of combinations that pop up in the data (the first column should ideally turn into the second column).

```
df <- data.frame(config = c("Prime Rose Ballroom 2,3,4,5,6 & South and E", 
                            "South Pacific ABC & 1/2", "South Pacific ABCDF&#2",
                            "South Pacific F & #3", "Ballroom 2-4", 
                            "Great Room 2 - 4", "109-110", "118-120 & 1 & H Grand Ballroom",
                            "155-157,160-165 & NC & SC", 
                            "312 - 313 & 316 - 317", "Ballroom A - C", 
                            "Grand Room A&C", "Banyan ABC",
                            "Bristelcone 1,2,3,8&9", "Egyptian A, B, C, & D", 
                            "Islander FGH & 1-3", "Terrace & 5", "Lagoon IJKL#2&4",
                            "Tunis B, C, D", "Main, Private, Splash, & River", 
                            "Room A/B/C/D", "Ballroom1,2,3,4&5", "Willow 4&5"), 
dedupedConfig = c(
"Prime Rose Ballroom 2, Prime Rose Ballroom 3, Prime Rose Ballroom 4, Prime Rose Ballroom 5, Prime Rose Ballroom 5, Prime Rose Ballroom 6, Prime Rose Ballroom South, Prime Rose Ballroom E",
"South Pacific A, South Pacific B, South Pacific C, South Pacific 1, South Pacific 2",
"South Pacific A, South Pacific B, South Pacific C, South Pacific D, South Pacific F, South Pacific 2","South Pacific F, South Pacific 3",
"Ballroom 2, Ballroom 3, Ballroom 4", "Great Room 2, Great Room 3, Great Room 4", 
"109, 110", "118 Grand Ballroom, 119 Grand Ballroom, 120 Grand Ballroom, 1 Grand Ballroom, H Grand Ballroom", 
"155, 156, 157, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, NC, SC", "312, 313, 316, 317",
"Ballroom A, Ballroom B, Ballroom C", "Grand Room A, Grand Room C", "Banyan A, Banyan B, Banyan C",
"Bristelcone 1, Bristelcone 2, Bristelcone 3, Bristelcone 8, Bristelcone 9", 
"Egyptian A, Egyptian B, Egyptian C, Egyptian D", 
"Islander F, Islander G, Islander H, Islander 1, Islander 2, Islander 3",
"Terrace, Terrace 5", "Lagoon I, Lagoon J, Lagoon K, Lagoon L, Lagoon 2, Lagoon 4",
"Tunis B, Tunis C, Tunis D", "Main, Private, Splash, River", "Room A, Room B, Room C, Room D",
"Ballroom 1, Ballroom 2, Ballroom 3, Ballroom 4, Ballroom 5 ", "Willow 4, Willow 5"))

# In case you export this into Excel for ease of seeing the data, you can run the following commands

library(stringr)
df$config <- str_squish(df$config)
df$dedupedConfig <- str_squish(df$dedupedConfig)
```

## Trying out the concat.split() function from the splitstackshape package

## Simply seperate on spaces however that won't work as a lot of the times the values do not have spaces in between them

```
library(splitstackshape)
df_breakdownSimple <- concat.split(df, 1, structure = "compact", sep = " ")
```

## Using multiple regular expressions to capture all combinations through which values in the first column (the dirty data) can be seperated however that also does not seem to work

```
df_breakdownMultipleSep <- concat.split(df, 1, structure = "compact", sep = paste0("\\b[A-Z]{2,}\\b", "[[:punct:]]", "[[:digit:]]", collapse = "|"))
```

Note that adding space or removing space or concatenating "Ballroom1,2,3,4&5" together (row 22) is intentional as it is shown as such in the actual data.

Other then manual entry (which is not feasible given the size of the dataframe > 6,000 rows), it looks like a complicated function would have to be written to address the myriad of irregularities in the data. I am fairly certain that I cannot come up with that complicated function (which warrants the post on Stackoverflow) and none of the problems I have searched for so far has matched the configuration I am facing. Thank you again

Comment: As mentioned in the initial post, the desired output should look like column 2 called "dedupedConfig". Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you!